# Right click select on .Net TreeNode

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, treeview

I am trying to show a popup menu on my treeview when users right click - allowing them to choose context sensitive actions to apply against the selected node.

At the moment the user has to left click node and then right click to choose.

Is it possible to make a right click on a node select that node - and if so what is the best method to do this.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Both left and right clicks fire a click event and cause the selection to change. However, in certain circumstances (that I haven't yet bothered to trace down) the selection will change from the node that was right clicked to the originally selected node.

In order to make sure that the right click changes the selection, you can forcibly change the selected node by using the `MouseDown` event:

```
treeView.MouseDown += (sender, args) =>
    treeView.SelectedNode = treeView.GetNodeAt(args.X, args.Y);
```

A little better, as one of the other posters pointed out, is to use the `NodeMouseClick` event:

```
treeView.NodeMouseClick += (sender, args) => treeView.SelectedNode = args.Node;
```

Comment: I agree. Simply adding this code to my Form's constructor did the trick for me. Thank you.

Comment: One issue I had with the NodeMouseClick approach is that it changes the selected node at the end of the NodeMouseClick event. So, for my purposes, I wanted the selected node to change before any context menu was displayed. In order to do that, I had to use the MouseDown approach.

Comment: Yes Coleman. I add validation: if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) ... (less charge)

Answer (score 16):

yes. Here is processing for `NodeMouseClick` event:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
      treeView1.SelectedNode = e.Node;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Drag a context menu strip onto the form then:

```
 private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
       // Display context menu for eg:
       ContextMenu1.Show();
   }
}
```