# Windows form: Treeview AfterClick event responding differently for Mouse Left and Mouse Right Click

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview in windows form. When I Left click a node in the treeview e.Node is showing correct value but when I right click the same node, e.Node is showing parent node value in the trreview Afterselect event. What could be the reason and how can I get the actual node even at Right click?

```
 private void trView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
 {    
     //e.Node is parent Node at Right click
     //e.Node is correct node at Left Click
        if (e.Node.IsSelected)
        {


        }
 }
```

Comment: [Right click select on .Net TreeNode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784258/right-click-select-on-net-treenode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked Post shows you how to select node using `MouseDown`.But you should know the `MouseDown` event triggers also when you click on `+/-` in `TreeView` while you want let the `+/-` perform it's original operation. So usually you need to check some other criteria to prevent unwanted behavior in `TreeView`:

- You can check if the mouse down is not over a `+/-` by checking the result of [`HitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hittest(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `TreeView`.
- You can check if the mouse down event is triggered by right mouse button by checking [`Button`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.button(v=vs.110).aspx) property of event args.

**Example**

```
private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode node = null;
    node = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
    var hti = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);

    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right ||
        hti.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.PlusMinus ||
        node == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    treeView1.SelectedNode = node;
    contextMenuStrip1.Show(treeView1, node.Bounds.Left, node.Bounds.Bottom);
}
```